# Why does this fail? (Incorrect Syntax Near '=')

Tags: sql-server

Why does this fail?

```
GO
    select vcCarrier1, vcTerminal1, vcZipEnd
      FROM   [GroundEDI].[dbo].[tblCustomerRouting]
      HAVING
      ( (CASE  WHEN vcCarrier1 = 'Carrier Code' 
        THEN vcTerminal1 = 'STM'
        ELSE NULL
        END)
       -- ELSE vcTerminal1 
       AND
       (CASE WHEN vcZipEnd = 'ZIP'
       THEN vcTerminal1 = 'Terminal Code'
       ELSE NULL
        END))
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: A `CASE` expr *returns* a value it cant assign a value; `THEN 'STM'`

Answer (score 1):

These lines are incorrect: `THEN vcTerminal1 = 'STM'` and `THEN vcTerminal1 = 'Terminal Code'`.
inside the `Then` clause of the `case` statement there can only be an expression that returns a scalar value, not a comparison and not an assignment.

I'm guessing (since it's not very clear from your attempt) it should be something like this:

```
SELECT vcCarrier1, vcTerminal1, vcZipEnd
FROM   [GroundEDI].[dbo].[tblCustomerRouting]
WHERE vcTerminal1 = 
    CASE WHEN vcCarrier1 = 'Carrier Code' THEN 
        'STM'
    WHEN vcZipEnd = 'ZIP' THEN
         'Terminal Code'
    ELSE 
        vcTerminal1 
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no logical expression in your having. By the way, having only makes sense on aggregated values.

Maybe this statement makes the result, which your trying to achieve?

```
select vcCarrier1, vcTerminal1, vcZipEnd
FROM   [GroundEDI].[dbo].[tblCustomerRouting]
WHERE (vcCarrier1 = 'Carrier Code'  AND  vcTerminal1 = 'STM') OR 
        (vcZipEnd = 'ZIP' AND vcTerminal1 = 'Terminal Code')
```

Best regards,
Ionic